# Recommended config settings to best secure an Asus Merlin router?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router

any setting recommendations to maximize security beyond this guys?  I put his settings in and stability does seem to have increased.  Internet dropped a couple times a day for 10 to 30 min. on LAN or wireless.  I only use it for laptops and cell phones. https://dfarq.homeip.net/recommended-asus-rt-ac66u-settings/

2. Any problem with "withdrawing" from the installed TrendMicro surveillance option?  I withdrew but don't see an option to reinstate it without an entire router reset.  24 hrs later, it seems possibly faster and more stable? IF anything.

(3) why aren't my images showing up?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ssz.jpg

Comment: I also just changed from my Xfinity DNS to cloudfare as well

My system: 7 month old Asus RT-AC66U_B1 with Merlin firmware running a purchased JRS eco-100 fork and 7 Month old Arris TM822 modem which I haven't touched the settings of.  All new xfinity cable and boxes outside last year.